# How to show Find/Replace Dialog on SpreadsheetGear workbook?

Tags: spreadsheetgear

How can I show from code SpreadsheetGear dialogs like Find/Replace?

There is WorkbookDesigner form which has most of those dialogs in main menu, but how can I implement it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Find and Replace" dialog is not part of SpreadsheetGear's public API and so cannot be instantiated from code.  Developers using Windows Forms have been able to "hack" this since a keyboard shortcut does exist to launch this dialog from the WinForms WorkbookView.  This has been done by sending a Ctrl+F keystroke to the [WorkbookView](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.Forms~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView.html), using something like the following:

```
workbookView.Focus();
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^f");
```

WPF doesn't support this model since it is part of Windows Forms.  However, it *appears* that using `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^f")` *might* work instead, but I make no guarantees of this.

Generally speaking, if a particular "dialog", such as the Find and Replace dialog, is not listed in the [SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms namespace](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.Forms~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms_namespace.html), then it is not available to instantiate from code.

Comment: Thanks, sendkeys does the job! But I still wonder why those dialogs are not a part of public API.